# Multiple y-values for one x value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I'm trying to graph the following values: 
0degr 0.24-0.27
20degr 0.22-0.28
40degr 0.22
60degr 0.2

How do I graph a range such as "0.24-0.27" in google sheets?

Thank you!

Comment: hi @Anthony, can your share a screenshot or anything that help us better understand your question ? ty !